# Training a modified fully-connected neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Take a simple 3 layer MLP neural network such as [this](https://github.com/hwalsuklee/tensorflow-mnist-MLP-batch_normalization-weight_initializers). Each hidden layer implements `y=xw+b` where `y` is the output activations matrix of the layer of shape `[batch_size, output_size]`, `x` is the input activations matrix of shape `[batch_size, input_size]`, `w` is the trainable weights matrix of shape `[input_size, output_size]` and `b` is the trainable bias vector of shape `[output_size]`.

Now modify the layer definition so each layer implements `y = x(w mod m) + b` where `m` is a trainable matrix similar to `w` and of same shape as `w`. Since tensorflow implements gradient of the modulo function for backprop, propagating gradients due to the added modulo shouldn't be an issue. Making this fairly trivial modification in the network breaks the MLP and the network stops learning altogether. In other words, the accuracy falls to ~10% for MNIST (10 digit classification) equivalent to random guessing.

Would anyone have any guesses as to why the network fails to learn with the added `mod` operator? I am able to implement `y=xw + (b mod m)` which works just fine. The problem seems to appear only when `mod` is used with the `xw` term.

Comment: Have you made sure that the output of the operation `y = x(w mod m) + b` as well as it's gradients are as you would expect? And do you include a softmax layer on `m` to make sure it's non-zero? If `m` becomes small you might experience issues with the gradients, so you could try and do `mod (m+1)` as a test.

Comment: Hey! I tested the gradients and they do seem to approach zero. I also added the softmax layer to `m` and the accuracy increased to ~20%. So I think that you're right that the edge cases are not being handled properly. The gradient for `w mod m` w.r.t `m` is undefined when `w` is an integer multiple of `m`. Need to figure out how tensorflow handles these cases. Secondly, when `softmax(m)` approaches zero, gradients w.r.t `m` would explode. `mod (m+1.)` doesn't work since `m` could be `-1`. Really odd thing is that `w mod k` where `k` is any constant doesn't work either.